# CoreImage.framework not found

Tags: macos, cocoa, frameworks, core-image

I'm developing a cocoa application.
I'm using CIFilter, and CIImage for applying core concepts in NSImage.

So I need to import `CoreImage.framework`. But I'm not getting the framework in my developer library folders. I'm searching the framework at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

and

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

But the CoreImage.framework is not there.

Can anyone please help me for adding CoreImage.framework in my code?

Thanks,
iPHoneDv

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Apple's documentation isn't super helpful in this regard, but you'll find CoreImage.framework hiding within QuartzCore.framework

So add "`QuartzCore.framework`" to your project and you should be all set.

Answer (score 2):

Import `QuartzCore.framework`

```
Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework
```